# Qt Creator, how do I add one c++ project to another?

Tags: qt-creator

This seems like something that should be really simple, yet there doesn't seem to be a way to do it as one would expect.

I have two separate c++ projects open in qt creator, and I would like to include/compile against one project in the other.

Here's my layout:

```
project_a/
    project_a.pro
    someheaders.h
    somecode.cpp
    main.cpp

project_b/
     project_b.pro
     someheaders.h
     somecode.cpp
     main.cpp
```

Basically I want to be able to include the files from project_a in project b. I have set project_a to be a dependency within project_b but that seems to have been wholly ineffectual as a means of using the two projects. What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to open & build both project as one, use meta-project with type `subdirs`:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += project_a project_b
# Use ordered build, from first subdir (project_a) to the last (project_b):
CONFIG += ordered
```

You should put subproject `any_name.pro` to directory `any_name`, and place this directory next to meta-project `.pro` file.

If you want include headers from other project, write `project_a.pri` file that contains, for example:

```
# PWD expands to directory where project_a.pri placed.
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/network
```

Than include this file to project_b.pro:

```
include(../project_a/project_a.pri)
```

If you want use project_a as library, change it to `TEMPLATE = lib` and add library with wizard, available in context menu when `project_b.pro` opened in editor.

Comment: Ok, so the first part of that worked. I have a subdirs project with the two projects inside it. But I still can't use headers from project_a within project_b. I've added a project_a.pri file in project_a but still can't access any of the headers.

Comment: I'm also unclear as to how to include them. I've managed to include them using `../project_a/header.h` but that seems less than elegant!